# Looking for a way to train a model to learn optimal parameters/hyperparameters of clustering

Tags: neural-networks, hyper-parameters, clustering, fine-tuning, semantic-networks

I have 5000 docs, each is a review. For each review, i'm plotting the sentences in a semantic dimension. Now, I'm applying clustering to these points for each review. The success of my model depends on how well these points are clustered. I'm looking for any clustering algorithm which can learn hyperparameters/parameters (eg. maximum distance between points, etc) from few reviews that I've hand-tagged (manually created clusters). As you can realize, the algorithm cannot expect any fixed number of clusters. So, the hyperparameters/parameters should be something like the bandwidth ( in mean-shift clustering ), or the lines. Any help would be appreciated. I'm looking for a paper with code, or any library that already has this.